# Need POJO object for the below yml structure to be autowired using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

application.yml

```
countries:
  country:
    - name: kenya
      insuffbal: test101
      inactive: test101
    - name: botswana
      insuffbal: test102
      inactive: test101
```

the above yml structure need to be mapped to a java object using Bean.

Countries.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "countries.ke")
public class Countries {
   //Need to map here - help me here
}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Countries.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        RepoProperties repoProperties = context.getBean(RepoProperties.class);
        repoProperties.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not understand what exactly you expect as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Just paste your `yaml` file there and choose source type `yaml`

Here is the bean file you need to define

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "countries")
public class Countries {

    private List<Country> country = null;

    public List<Country> getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(List<Country> country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public static class Country {

        private String name;
        private String insuffbal;
        private String inactive;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getInsuffbal() {
            return insuffbal;
        }

        public void setInsuffbal(String insuffbal) {
            this.insuffbal = insuffbal;
        }

        public String getInactive() {
            return inactive;
        }

        public void setInactive(String inactive) {
            this.inactive = inactive;
        }
    }
}
```

Now just Autowire `Countries` anywhere you want to use.

Comment: Thanks. It has generated 3 java files but how to configure component and autowired to those generated java classes

Comment: Updated the answer